# Generate random sparse matrix filled with values greater than 1 python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

The method available in python scipy `sps.rand()` generates sparse matrix of random values in the range (0,1). How can we generate discrete random values greater than 1 like 2, 3,etc. ? Any method in scipy, numpy ?

Comment: By using [the other method defined](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.random.html#scipy.sparse.random).

Answer (score 1):

`sparse.rand` calls `sparse.random`.  `random` adds a optional `data_rvs`.

I haven't used `data_rvs`.  It can probably emulate the dense `randint`, but definition is more complicated.

Another option is to generate the random floats and then convert them with a bit of math to the desired integers.  You have to be a little careful since some operations will produce a Sparse Efficiency warning.  You want operations that will change the nonzero values without touching the zeros.

(I suspect the `data_rvs` parameter was added in newer Scipy version, but I don't see an indication in the docs).